# Get storage engine in MySql

Tags: mysql

how do i get the storage engine used by a specific database in MySql?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or by querying information_schema:

```
SELECT engine 
  FROM information_schema.tables 
 WHERE table_schema = 'test' 
   AND table_name = 'q';

+--------+
| engine |
+--------+
| MyISAM |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name
```

will work for a given table.